# Compile sass files to hashed css using webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass

to compile my .scss files I use webpack.

What i want to achieve is to get for example

```
styles.b0eda78ad870282c8cb9fd58884415d7.css
```

instead of

```
styles.css
```

When I add to webpack option [hash] (now commented in source) - then every change in .scss files generate new .css files. For example 3 changes in .scss will generate 3 new files with different hashes:

```
themeA.b0eda78ad870282c8cb9fd58884415d7.css
themeA.2c0521243fe51696a6d08ae5443a6721.css
themeA.6ebd2d65f4d311fbac8441141826a9a8.css
```

I want only to update one css file with new hash and do not create new files.

My webpack configuration

```
const themeA = `${mainDirectory}/commons/themeA.scss`;
const themeB = `${mainDirectory}/commons/scss/shop/themeB.scss`;
const themeC = `${mainDirectory}/commons/themeC.scss`;
const themeD = `${mainDirectory}/commons/scss/shop/themeD.scss`;

let sassFiles;
const themeMap = new Map([
  ['a', themeA],
  ['b', themeB],
  ['c', themeC],
  ['d', themeD],
]);

if (theme === undefined) {
  sassFiles = [...themeMap.values()];
} else {
  sassFiles = [
    `${mainDirectory}/commons/${theme}.scss`,
    `${mainDirectory}/commons/scss/shop/${theme}_shop.scss`,
  ];
}

module.exports = {
  entry: [...sassFiles],
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(mainDirectory, 'commons'),
    filename: 'hot/sassBundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true,
              name: '[name].css',
              // hashed css
              // name: '[name].[hash].css',
              outputPath: '/css',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'extract-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false,
              sourceMap: !buildMode,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: !buildMode,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: !buildMode,
              convertToAbsoluteUrls: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
    ],
  },


  plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({}),
    new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([
      {
        dir: `${mainDirectory}/commons/css/`,
        test: [/\.css$/],
        rules: [
          {
            search: /\/\*# sourceURL.+\\*/g,
            replace: '',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
};
```

Comment: did you try to build production build? In prod mode it should concat them into one css file

Comment: but I want to upload css files to .html file in another way and i don't want to work on or commit hundreds of new css files.

Comment: I believe this Gulp boilerplate does what you are looking for https://github.com/vigetlabs/blendid You will need separate “watch” and “build” tasks which will allow you to only hash the files on build. You can also delete the contents of the dist folder on each rebuild to avoid multiple copies.